# Unable to open firefox 35 using selenium web driver 2.45.0

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

I am unable to run my selenium webdriver script on Mozilla 35.0.1 , based on suggestions and comments on stackoverflow. I downgraded firefox to firefox 28.0.1 but still facing the same problem . Browser is getting loaded but it does not write url link in address bar. Same script is running on firefox 17.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue when upgrading Firefox.

Please try 
`driver.get("");` method 
before the line

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this problem arises in the case of `Mozilla` `Firefox`. Try `Google` `Chrome`.

I tried several methods and it didn't helped me. So I choose Chrome.
Chrome can be opened up bu using the below code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "ChromeDriver Location in your PC");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Please add this Library also.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```